# EventEmitter on @Output don't works

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a problem with this:

```
@Output() searchFilter = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

then

```
filter() {
this.searchFilter.emit('soy un emit');}
```

And in the view I call this :

`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" [(ngModel)]="searchFilter" (input)="filter()" >`

In the parent

```
<app-header (searchFilter)="filter($event)"></app-header>
```

This code works without problems in other project but now this gives me the following error

```
ERROR TypeError: this.searchFilter.emit is not a function
```

Any idea?

Comment: why do you double bind the input with the event emitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[(ngModel)]="searchFilter"
```

causes a string from the input element to be assigned to `searchFilter` and a string doesn't have an `emit` method.

It's not entirely clear what you try to accomplish to give more concrete advice to fix your problem.

A guess

```
@Output() searchFilterChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
@Input() searchFilter:string;

filter() {
  this.searchFilterChange.emit('soy un emit');
}
```

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" 
  [ngModel]="searchFilter" (ngModelChange)="filter()" >
```

Comment: I fix the problem with this. I was using the same variable to save the string input value and emit this.

`searchText: string;
  @Output() searchFilter = new EventEmitter<string>();`

`searchTextToParent() {
    this.searchFilter.emit(this.searchText);
  }`

Now this works